# C Reading binary data into struct

Tags: c, struct, binary-data

I have a struct

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t type;  // 1B -> 1B
    uint16_t hash; // 2B -> 3B
    uint16_t id;   // 2B -> 5B
    uint32_t ip;   // 4B -> 9B
    uint16_t port; // 2B -> 11B
} Data;
```

and some binary data (which is a stored instance of Data on disk)

```
const unsigned char blob[11] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x7b, 0x00, 0xea, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x59, 0x01, 0x00 };
```

I want to "read" the `blob` into my struct, the first byte `0x00` corresponds to `type`, the second and third byte `0x00, 0x7b` correspond to `hash`, etc.

I can't just do `Data *data = (Data *)blob`, since the actual size of `Data` will probably be bigger than `11` Bytes (Faster RAM access or something. Not relevant here.) The point is `sizeof(Data) == 16` and the representation in RAM may be different than the compact one on disk.

So how can I "import" my blob into a Data struct without having to use `memcpy` for every attribute? Aka what's nicest/simplest solution for this in C?

Comment: I'd use `union` for the overlapping fields (other than `type`).

Comment: @EugeneSh. They're not overlapping, I need all of them. But I can admit, that my naming convention may not be perfect.

Comment: Just write to disk directly from the struct, and read from disk directly into the struct.

Comment: `#pragma pack`?

Comment: @dbush If I could I would, but I'm getting the data like this.

Comment: I think you do need to use memcpy to be safe, since you can't assume how the packing of the struct will work for any particular build of the code.  @dbush - dangerous if the packing changes.

Comment: Two structures? One packed for file-access, and one not packed for memory access. Create functions which creates one from the other. Or read the 11 bytes into a `uint8_t` buffer, and construct the structure from the raw byte data.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError looks promising. But probably not very portable? And I should probably get the data into a non packed struct asap?
- I hate your username :*)

Comment: Another alternative is to read each field one by one, and just assign it to the structure member. Or maybe even directly into the individual structure members directly.

Comment: The portable way is to deserialize each member individually.

Comment: Oh and with all of this, no matter how you solve it, you need to be able to handle byte ordering for the multi-byte values.

Answer (score 2):

> The point is `sizeof(Data) == 16` and the representation in RAM may be different than the compact one on disk.

Since you cannot rely on the data layout in the file to match that of the in-memory structure, standard C does not provide an alternative to working member by member.

But reading the data from disk is potentially a different question from reading it from an array.  I suppose you imagine reading one or more whole raw records into memory and then copying from there in some way, but if you can rely on the sizes and endianness of the individual fields matching between structure and disk then you could consider this:

```
Data item;

if (fread(&item.type, sizeof(item.type), 1, input_file) == 0) handle_error();
if (fread(&item.hash, sizeof(item.hash), 1, input_file) == 0) handle_error();
if (fread(&item.ip,   sizeof(item.ip),   1, input_file) == 0) handle_error();
if (fread(&item.id,   sizeof(item.id),   1, input_file) == 0) handle_error();
if (fread(&item.port, sizeof(item.port), 1, input_file) == 0) handle_error();
```

That lets the stream handle the buffering (which it will, unless you disable that), relieves you of counting bytes, and is pretty clear.  Five calls to `fread()` might be a bit more expensive than five to `memcpy()`, but you're unlikely to notice the difference next to the cost of opening the file and transfering data from it.

If you do need to populate the structure from an in-memory array containing raw bytes from the file, however, then per-member `memcpy()` is the most portable way.  And quite possibly more efficient than you think.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the right sided bytes in the blob array correspond to a higher weight
than the left sided bytes, then, a simple solution would be using bitwise operators in the following way:

```
void importFromBlob(const unsigned char *blob, Data *data) {
    // Import type
    data->type = blob[0];

    // Import hash 
    data->hash = (blob[1] << 8) | blob[2];  //assembled as 0x007b in your exp

    // Import id 
    data->id = (blob[3] << 8) | blob[4];

    // Import ip 
    data->ip = (uint32_t)(blob[5]) | (uint32_t)(blob[6] << 8) | (uint32_t)(blob[7] << 16) | (uint32_t)(blob[8] << 24);

    // Import port
    data->port = (blob[9] << 8) | blob[10];
}
```

Comment: That might work, but it assumes that the data are stored in big-endian order in the source.  It could be adjusted to assume little-endian order instead, but if one wants to assume the machine byte order, *whatever that may be*, then you need `memcpy()` or an equivalent.

Comment: Got your point, your right, and thanks for the clarification @john. I will be sure to consider these cases moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid multiple reads or byte copies for this particular structure is to pad the structure explicitly with 3 initial bytes and 2 trailing bytes:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t pad0[3];  // 3 bytes at offset 0, unused
    uint8_t type;     // 1 byte  at offset 3
    uint16_t hash;    // 2 bytes at offset 4
    uint16_t id;      // 2 bytes at offset 6
    uint32_t ip;      // 4 bytes at offset 8
    uint16_t port;    // 2 bytes at offset 12
    uint8_t pad1[2];  // 2 bytes at offset 14, unused. total: 16 bytes
} Data;
```

You would read the data with a single `fread`:

```
    Data mydata;
    if (fread(&mydata.type, 1, 11, fp) == 11) {
        // mydata was read successfully
        // fields can be used directly assuming correct endianness.
    } else {
        // read error
    }
```

Copying from the memory blob is also a single call to `memcpy`:

```
    const unsigned char blob[11] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x7b, 0x00, 0xea, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x59, 0x01, 0x00
    };
    memcpy(&mydata.type, bloc, 11);
```

Reading the binary data requires opening the file in binary mode `"rb"`, `"wb"`...

Writing the data in a single `fwrite` is done with

```
    if (fwrite(&mydata.type, 1, 11, fp) == 11) ...
```

This trick works for the structure in the question, but might not work in many other cases:

- if the endianness in the file differs from the CPUs,
- if the the sequence of items larger than one byte is not favorable.

So in the general case, you may have to use `memcpy` to copy chunks of the compact byte oriented representation to the structure used ni memory, adjusting for potential endianness differences.  `memcpy` with small fixed sizes is usually expanded inline efficiently generating very few instructions as can be verified on using the [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sKdEshq78).

Comment: That's an insightful observation about the OP's particular `struct`, but it's not generalizable.  And it's helpful to them only if they are in fact free to modify the `struct` definition, which might or might not be the case.  But if they *can* modify the structure then it's nice.